# Deshacer o borrar enlace ln debian

Tags: bash

Estaba creando un servidor DDNS, necesitaba hacer unos enlaces simbólicos de esta forma;

```
cd /var/cache/bind/

ln -s /etc/bind/zones/db.marcsanchezg.local .
ln -s /etc/bind/zones/db.192.168.3 .
```

Pero se me olvidó poner el punto espaciado del final, y el tutorial indica que si no lo pongo no se guardará. Puse esto:

```
cd /var/cache/bind/

ln -s /etc/bind/zones/db.marcsanchezg.local
ln -s /etc/bind/zones/db.192.168.3
```

Ahora al crearlas de nuevo me aparece el error:

```
Fallo al crear el enlace simbólico X: El fichero ya existe.
```

Como puedo deshacer o borrar el enlace anterior y ponerlo de nuevo con el punto final?

Comment: por lo que veo, si no pones el punto crea un enlace simbólico con el mismo nombre que el fichero al que apuntas, por tanto no es problemático.